# Installing TensorFlow for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I am following this link to create a .whl package for Raspberry Pi:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi

Specifically, I am running the following command:

`tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI \ tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh PI_ONE`

and I get the following message: "RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required"

Checking the Python version the following information is provided:

`...~/tensorflow$ python --version`
`Python 3.5.2`

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Gus

Comment: why dont you just use pip?

Answer (score 0):

Install anaconda. Create an env with python 3.5, activate it and then run the script

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sarath, Obayhan for taking the time to try to help me with this problem. After a lot of frustration, I decided to upgrade Ubuntu to 20.04 LTS and everything works as specified in the Tensorflow website.